# Facebook signed_request returns NULL

Tags: facebook, request, signed

I created a tab application and deployed to three of my fan pages.

When visitors access my fan page, my web backend will grab pageID from signed_request, so that it can log which fan page that user is accessing.

It works well for facebook users who do not have admin role of any fan pages. But if an user with admin role access those fan pages, I can not only get Null value from signed_request parameter.

Anyone knows why? How can I fix it?

Thanks

Ian